# terminal error message not cleared from the last session

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

a error message popped up when I was using virtualenvwrapper incorrectly, the error message is shown below:

```
    /usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for    'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.
    If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader, check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 and that PATH is set properly.
```

This error message shows up every time I open the terminal, and can be cleared by ctrl-L.

Rebooting the computer and rm .bash_history doesn't fix this problem.

Comment: Is `virtualenv` invoked by your shell's startup files? Check in `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` if you're using `bash` as your shell.

Comment: It's not that it's "not cleared". It is printed again, in every new terminal.

Comment: @Kusalananda That is what happened. I totally forgot that I had changed the .bashrc file. Thanks, you are awesome.

Comment: @egmont You are right, thanks for helping. I removed the virtualenv lines in my .bashrc and it no longer shows up.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved after the user removed a `virtualenv` invocation from their `~/.bashrc` file.

Since `virtualenv` was started from `~/.bashrc`, its startup message appeared in each new terminal window.  It was therefore not an issue of *not clearing* the terminal, but of *not starting `virtualenv`*.